# cannot connect to wireless ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, internet, asus

I have looked at many related questions about how Ubuntu 16.04 cannot connect to wireless internet, but nothing so far has helped me.

It says it is connected to wireless, but it does not load any pages.

My computer is an ASUS X751L.  I cannot do any work at home or in coffee shops.  Sometimes in coffee shops it will say it is connected, but if they have a password, the prompt will not come up so I cannot enter it in and connect that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after removing the gnome keyring.  Reinstalling the keyring fixed it.  But another workaround I found is to attempt to connect, let it fail, and then you can "edit" the connection.  In the Edit window, you can add the password.